# Gulp-replace not working with SCSS

Tags: gulp

I tried

```
gulp.task('sass', function () {
  return gulp.src(['./scss/*.scss'])
        .pipe($.replace(/_VIEWPORT_WIDTH_/g,conf.project.viewport||640))
        .pipe($.sass({errLogToConsole: true}))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./resources/css/'));
});
```

still not working.
pipe replace after SCSS will work,but SCSS can not do math during the process.

```
gulp.task('sass', function () {
  return gulp.src(['./scss/*.scss'])
    .pipe($.sass({errLogToConsole: true}))
     .pipe($.replace(/_VIEWPORT_WIDTH_/g,conf.project.viewport||640))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./resources/css/'));
});
```

any suggestion?I know there is an ugly way,but that's too Grunt

```
gulp.task('sass', function () {
  return gulp.src(['./scss/*.scss'],{buffer:true})
        .pipe($.replace(/_VIEWPORT_WIDTH_/g,conf.project.viewport||640))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./tmp/scss/'))
        .pipe($.sass({errLogToConsole: true}))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./resources/css/')).on('end',function(){
          del(['./tmp/scss/'], {force: true});
        });
});
```

Comment: What is `$.sass` and what is its version?

Comment: It's gulp-sass,the latest version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because the latest version of gulp-sass (and perhaps every previous version) has a serious bug / design flaw -- it discards changes to file contents from earlier in the pipeline. I reported this at [dlmanning/gulp-sass#158](https://github.com/dlmanning/gulp-sass/issues/158) and it's supposed to be fixed in the next major version (v2) I believe.

Comment: I've tried 2.0.0-alpha.1,still not working.install by "npm install gulp-sass@next --save-dev".Does it work in your case?

Comment: I didn't try it with your code, or try the release you just mentioned, but the branch I was instructed to try in dlmanning/gulp-sass#158 fixed the test cases I posted in that issue.

Comment: @unbuglee v2 has been released -- have you tried it?

Comment: @unbuglee Can you create a minimal GitHub repo that reproduces the problem?

Comment: I have a much better project for you,a real project. https://github.com/unbug/generator-webappstarter ,after you create a project by it,it should be easy to modify line 126 in the gulpfile to be the same like my question.